# Angle code needed

Tags: code

I have constructed this triangle but I need to include a value for an angle between the side that is labelled c and the side of value 5.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) node[midway,below] {$5$}

   -- (4,4) node[midway,right] {$ $}

   -- (0,0) node[midway,left] {$c$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

by help of `tikz` library `angles` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0) coordinate (a)
              -- node[below] {$5$}
        (4,0) coordinate (b)
              -- node[midway,right] {$ $}
        (4,4) coordinate (c)
              -- node[midway,left] {$c$}
        (a) ;
\pic [draw, angle radius=9mm, "$\alpha$"] {angle = b--a--c};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PaulFerris just informing you that there is a "tick-like" button near the "upvote" button. Its functionality is that if the one who made the question press this first button the answer is been marked as accepted and thus the future visitors will see immediately that the answer works.